# How to create multiple layers from a single csv file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have one csv file that holds coordinate point data for different vehicles (below is an image of the csv). [image] I want each vehicle to have its own layer when I upload the data as a delimited text file. How can I do this without uploading the data for each vehicle as a separate file?
Here is how I would want the data to look.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get the appearance you want without having a layer per vehicle. Instead, just symbolize the layer with a different symbol/color for each vehicle.

After loading the CSV file, go to the layer properties style pane. Select categorized for the symbol style and VID for the column. Click on classify and then adjust the colors if they're not to your liking.  (This is for 2.X - I'm not running 3.0, so there might be some difference in the interface.)

Comment: The file is quite large (401 KB) and my computer stalls QGIS whenever I try to upload the entire file. Does anyone know of a way I could fix this other than by bisecting the file and uploading it in 2 parts?

Comment: 401KB is not a large file. I just tested adding a 6.7MB file, ~46K records, 18 fields. The dataset loads and displays in 2-3 seconds. This is on a 5+ year old i7 laptop running QGIS 2.18 under Windows 7. If you're willing to place your file someplace on the web, I'll try loading it.